# Why didn't Federation use a sabotage-plot with the mutants?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

A continuation of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139440/7885) question. In [Statistical Probabilities episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Statistical_Probabilities_(episode)) Bashir works with a group of genetically engineered humans. At some point all of them (except Bashir) are trying to

> meet Weyoun and Dukat to provided them with Federation secrets making Dominion invasion in Aphla Quadrand possible, quick and successful to the Dominion. This idea is prevented by Bashir and Odo.

Why this so extremely obvious (at least to me) opportunity wasn't exploited by Federation?

> Episode ends with Odo saying to surprised Weyoun and Dukat that "they" will not come. Why didn't Federation use this situation to feed both enemy leaders with **false** information? In other words, why a sabotage or diversion was not used in this situation?

Is there any reasonable explanation, why Federation failed to make use of such a good opportunity?

Comment: That would be *dishonest*.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that Sisko and the station crew **only had a few minutes to prepare for the meeting.**

Given that anything less than what Weyoun had been promised (e.g. "*some information that could be very beneficial to us.*") would be disregarded as a probable trap, there's really no good way for Sisko to have used the meeting to disseminate misinformation.

In the end he decides to send Odo along to escort the Vorta back to his quarters.

Comment: But... still! Both Weyoun and Dukat did not know, _whom_ they're going to meet. Sisko could send someone not known by these two, to request that meeting must be postponed two days or so, pretending that Federation being dangerously to close (an could possible intercept messenger) Or something like that.